# How to install Windows Server 2012 R2 in KvM on Linux?

Tags: centos, windows, virtual-machine, kvm, remote-desktop

When installing Windows to a KVM I have gotten to the following:

```
# virt-install \
 --name vm1 \
 --ram=2048 \
 --vcpus=2 \
 --disk path=/vm-images/vm1.img,size=15 \
 --cdrom /root/dvd1.iso
```

This will however boot Windows but I'll have no way to run through the interactive install.

Is my only way to build a zero-touch type install locally then push that so Windows installs automatically? The other part that gets me lost is how will I know it's IP or if RDP is enabled so I can login remotely to the Windows Machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `qemu` for this : `qemu-x86_64 -m 1024 -boot d -cdrom windows.iso -hda mydisk.img`. Use `qemu-img` prior to this to create `mydisk.img`.

Answer (score 1):

virt-install will create the VM and kick off the installation process. You can access the process via console using virt-manager or virt-viewer (remote-viewer) or directly via the VNC or SPICE console. The extra option to add is `--graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0 --noautoconsole`